# compactness criterion for random variables in L2

Tags: probability-theory, compactness, brownian-motion

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables such that their second moments are uniformly bounded. I would like to know a compactness criterion for this case.

In analysis, if $K$ is a bounded subset in $L^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ is a domain in $R^n$, a compactness criteria is given as following. $K$ is relative compact if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, there are $\delta>0$, $G$ compact subset of $\Omega$ such that for every $f\in K$, for every $h\in R^n$ with $|h|<\delta$
$$\int_\Omega |f(x+h)-f(x)|^2dx<\epsilon^2 $$
and
$$\int_{\Omega- G}|f(x)|^2dx<\epsilon^2 $$
where the functions are extended by 0 outside $\Omega$.

I find out that for random variables, the domain $\Omega$ is very vague, and in general there is no topological structure on it. So one example that I have in mind is $X_n=\int_0^1 f_n(B_s)ds$ where $B$ is Brownian motion and $f_n$ is as nice as possible. Is there a compact criteria for this case?

Answer (score 2):

This notion is called [tightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) of a sequence of measures.

You can apply it in probability theory with the sequence $P\#{X_n}$ 
of the image probabilities under the action of $X_n$:
$$
P\#{X_n}(A) =  P(X_n\in A)
$$

You transfer the 
topology issues to the (metric, often polish) space $\mathcal X$ where
$$
X:\Omega \to \mathcal X
$$

---

Note also that in the case of random variables with $2^{\text{nd}}$ moment bounded,
you have a [uniformly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) sequence. In this case, the sequence converge in $L^1$ iff it converges in probability.

Comment: mookid, thanks for the comment. I am aware of tightness, but it only implies compactness in distributions. Compactness in probability is also something I am not sure about. What I am really looking for is a criterion for compactness in $L^2$ sense.